# How to do this first step in my programming project in python 2.7

Tags: python

this is the first steps:
 Define an instance method named "roll" that takes one argument (besides self).  Give the parameter an appropriate name to hold the list of indexes we need to roll.
Create a for loop that will traverse through the parameter list.
Inside the loop, change the dice for each index value in the list to a random number from 1 to 6.  Remember that to refer to the instance variable you must precede it with self and a dot.

this is what i have so far

```
from random import randint

class Dice(object):
     def __init__(self):
        self.dice = []
        x = 0
        while x < 5:
            self.dice.append(str(randint(1,6)))
            x += 1

hand = Dice() 
print hand.dice
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Then keep going. If you have a specific problem or difficulty with the code, you can ask a question here, but you can't just post a brief and expect people to do it for you.,

Comment: You're on the right track, so just break it down piece-by-piece.

Comment: When it says to define an instance method named "roll" in the first step, I thought an instance method was just like " def __init__(self, x, y):". So how do I actually name an instance method roll, since I don't see a place whee the name fits in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description of the task is not 100% clear.
Does this code solve your problem?

```
from random import randint

class Dice(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dice = []

    def roll(self,how_many):
        for i in range(how_many):
            self.dice.append(randint(1,6))

hand = Dice() 
hand.roll(5)
print(hand.dice)
```